# Match first part of pathname and number at end of line

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have the following type of output from a `find` and `grep` pipe

```
./Columbia/815425_0001104659-11-049107.txt:         CENTRAL INDEX KEY:              0000815425
./Columbia/815425_0001104659-12-060231.txt:         CENTRAL INDEX KEY:              0000815425
./Columbia/815425_0001104659-13-066298.txt:         CENTRAL INDEX KEY:              0000815425
./Dimensional Advisors/355437_0001137439-04-000108.txt:         CENTRAL INDEX KEY:              0000355437
./Dimensional Advisors/355437_0001137439-05-000205.txt:         CENTRAL INDEX KEY:              0000355437
./Dimensional Advisors/355437_0001137439-06-000306.txt:         CENTRAL INDEX KEY:              0000355437
./Dimensional Advisors/355437_0001137439-08-000364.txt:         CENTRAL INDEX KEY:              0000355437
./Dimensional Advisors/355437_0001137439-09-000076.txt:         CENTRAL INDEX KEY:              0000355437
./Dimensional Advisors/355437_0001137439-12-000295.txt:         CENTRAL INDEX KEY:              0000355437
./Dimensional Advisors/355437_0001140361-10-035592.txt:         CENTRAL INDEX KEY:              0000355437
```

I would like to obtain

```
Columbia 0000815425
Columbia 0000815425
Columbia 0000815425
Dimensional Advisors 0000355437
Dimensional Advisors 0000355437
Dimensional Advisors 0000355437
Dimensional Advisors 0000355437
Dimensional Advisors 0000355437
Dimensional Advisors 0000355437
Dimensional Advisors 0000355437
```

I was thinking `sed` and `grep`, but I am stuck with how to combine everything: matching the first part: (how do I match just before the `/`?)

```
erik Funds$ cat myoutput | egrep -o "[A-Z].*/"
Columbia/
Columbia/
Columbia/
Dimensional Advisors/
Dimensional Advisors/
Dimensional Advisors/
Dimensional Advisors/
Dimensional Advisors/
Dimensional Advisors/
Dimensional Advisors/
```

and the last 10 digit numbers:

```
erik Funds$ cat myoutput | egrep -o "[0-9]{10}$"
0000815425
0000815425
0000815425
0000355437
0000355437
0000355437
0000355437
0000355437
0000355437
0000355437
```

Comment: `how do I match just before the /?` ... use perl regex with lookahead.. `grep -oP "[A-Z].*(?=/)"`

Comment: too bad `cut -f` can't index from the end of the list

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`awk` with `/` as field separator, and then printing field 2 and field 3 (with necessary zero padding):

```
... | awk -F/ '{ printf("%s %010d\n", $2, $3) }'
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt 
./Columbia/815425_0001104659-11-049107.txt:         CENTRAL INDEX KEY:              0000815425
./Columbia/815425_0001104659-12-060231.txt:         CENTRAL INDEX KEY:              0000815425
./Columbia/815425_0001104659-13-066298.txt:         CENTRAL INDEX KEY:              0000815425
./Dimensional Advisors/355437_0001137439-04-000108.txt:         CENTRAL INDEX KEY:              0000355437
./Dimensional Advisors/355437_0001137439-05-000205.txt:         CENTRAL INDEX KEY:              0000355437
./Dimensional Advisors/355437_0001137439-06-000306.txt:         CENTRAL INDEX KEY:              0000355437
./Dimensional Advisors/355437_0001137439-08-000364.txt:         CENTRAL INDEX KEY:              0000355437
./Dimensional Advisors/355437_0001137439-09-000076.txt:         CENTRAL INDEX KEY:              0000355437
./Dimensional Advisors/355437_0001137439-12-000295.txt:         CENTRAL INDEX KEY:              0000355437
./Dimensional Advisors/355437_0001140361-10-035592.txt:         CENTRAL INDEX KEY:              0000355437

$ awk -F/ '{ printf("%s %010d\n", $2, $3) }' file.txt
Columbia 0000815425
Columbia 0000815425
Columbia 0000815425
Dimensional Advisors 0000355437
Dimensional Advisors 0000355437
Dimensional Advisors 0000355437
Dimensional Advisors 0000355437
Dimensional Advisors 0000355437
Dimensional Advisors 0000355437
Dimensional Advisors 0000355437
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$ sed -E 's|^\./([^/]+)/.*\s([0-9]+)$|\1 \2|' myoutput
Columbia 0000815425
Columbia 0000815425
Columbia 0000815425
Dimensional Advisors 0000355437
Dimensional Advisors 0000355437
Dimensional Advisors 0000355437
Dimensional Advisors 0000355437
Dimensional Advisors 0000355437
Dimensional Advisors 0000355437
Dimensional Advisors 0000355437
```

- `-E` extended regular expression
- `^\./` match `./` at beginning of line
- `([^/]+)` capture non `/` characters
- `/.*\s` match `/` and any number of characters followed by white-space character
- `([0-9]+)$` capture digits at end of line
- `\1 \2` paste the captured groups with space in between

`sed` allows to use any delimiter except `\` and newline, so using `|` here to avoid escaping `/`

Answer (score 2):

#### awk - using FS splitting

If you set `awk` to split the input on slash delimiters, and then resplit on space delimiters, you can pick out the correct fields:

```
<infile awk '{ n=$2; FS=" +"; $0=$0; print n, $NF; FS="/" }' FS=/
```

#### GNU awk - using FPAT field description

If you describe the fields correctly to with `FPAT` you can get the desired results. Here is an example that works with your input:

```
<infile awk '{ print $1, $NF }' FPAT='[[:alnum:][:space:]]+'
```

#### Output

```
Columbia               0000815425
Columbia               0000815425
Columbia               0000815425
Dimensional Advisors               0000355437
Dimensional Advisors               0000355437
Dimensional Advisors               0000355437
Dimensional Advisors               0000355437
Dimensional Advisors               0000355437
Dimensional Advisors               0000355437
Dimensional Advisors               0000355437
```

Comment: Not the output OP wants i'm afraid..

Comment: @heemayl: My mistake. The updated version produces the correct result, although is not as simple ...

Comment: Equivalent but less fiddly: `awk '{split($1,a,"/"); print a[2],$NF}'`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: using `$1` will not capture multi-word arguments.

Comment: Argh, you're right. sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative solution, piping your data through `tr` and `cut` :

```
…|tr ':' '/'|cut -d'/' -f2,5|tr -d '/'
```

The first `tr` replaces `:` with `/`, so that `cut` can use `/` as a delimiter to isolate the last column, as it already does for the second one.  Since you extract several columns, `cut`'s output will contain a `/` as a separator, unless you use its `--output-delimiter`, but it's shorter to simply delete this character using `tr -d`.

If you don't want the multiple spaces you can add a pipe through `sed` :

```
…|sed 's/  */ /g'
```